# Fit container height to responsive image in IE11

Tags: html, css

So I have the a container `<div>` that has a responsive image inside of it. The problem is, the container div has a width restriction and I want that to fit the height of the responsive image. Can anyone propose the changes I need in my CSS?

In my snippet below, you could see that the black background color is visible (which means that the `<div>` doesn't fit the height of the image.

EDIT:

Sorry, my initial snippet was incomplete (I've removed the old one). This should be the one I'm having problem with. This problem is only in IE11 by the way.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  background-color: black;
}

.container img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <article class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/800x600">
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Please google things. this has been asked many times, there is **no** need to ask again

Comment: @vsync - Yeah, sorry about that. I posted an incomplete snippet, I'm having trouble googling the new snippet I have above.

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align:top`

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  background-color: black;
}

.container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```

Comment: This or make the image tag display block

Comment: Sorry I posted an incomplete snippet. That `display: block` which I've tried before won't work on the new snippet above **only in IE11**.

I also tried the `vertical-align: top` but it still didn't work.

Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`<img>` is a inline tag which show unwanted space after it so you can use a small css to make it block tag and that is `display:block` which removes the unwanted space

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  background-color: black;
}

.container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I posted an incomplete snippet. That `display: block` which I've tried before won't work on the new snippet above **only in IE11**. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: IE doesn't support some of the common properties. Try using this js with IE hack `<!--[if lt IE 11]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->`. This JS enable all the properties in IE

Comment: I believe IE11 supports all the CSS props I used above. Which property did you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Add a 1px min-height to the **.container** then the height calculate right in IE11

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  background-color: black;
  min-height:1px;
}

.container img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <article class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/800x600">
  </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add `display: block` style to your image styles like this..

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  background-color: black;
}

.container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I posted an incomplete snippet. That `display: block` which I've tried before won't work on the new snippet above **only in IE11**. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
.banner {
    background: url('../images/Banner.jpg') no-repeat center;
    background-size: -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var w_ht = $(window).height();
    $('.banner').css({'height': w_ht});
    });
</script>

<div class="banner"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an old article, but  had the same problem and didn't find one of these answers helpful, so [here's](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp) what worked for me.

I just had to add the aspect-ratio to the div, that's containing the img/ imgs. In my case  1920x460px images, which means by implication an aspect ratio of

`padding-top: (420/1960)*100%; = 23.958333%;`

Hope someone else can solve his/her problem like this as well!